# Showing variables Printf

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

My question is that in the last statement I want to show the gc variable in the last `printf`. I mean: if you introduced 4 celsius, I want to show that 4 in the as well, but I dont know how to show an variable in a `printf`.

```
//celsius a radianes
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    float gc, gf = ( gc * 9 / 5) + 32;

    printf("\n Programa para convertir de Grados celsius a grados Fahrenheit\nIntroduzca un numero en grados celsius:\n");

    scanf("%f", &gc);
    gf = ( gc * 9 / 5) + 32;
    printf( "gc en Grados en fahrenheit = %.4f\n", gf); 
}
```

Comment: What is the value of gc?

Comment: `printf("%.4fC is %.4fF\n", gc, gf);`

Comment: Not an answer, but `float gc, gf = ( gc * 9 / 5) + 32;` -> `float gc, gf;`, the initialisation is pointless.

Comment: I think that @pgm has given you the answer

Comment: Always (yes, **always**) prefer `double` when dealing with floating-point (don't even consider `float` or `long double` unless you have a very strong reason -- "*my teacher told me to use `float`*" is only a strong reason after you ask for justification/clarification).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question edited heavily (sorry OP)

> How to print `gc` and `gf` in print?
>
> ```
> printf( "gc en Grados en fahrenheit = %.4f\n", gf);
> ```

Just add another %specifier and the corresponding variable

```
printf( "%.4f en Grados en fahrenheit = %.4f\n", gc, gf);
//       ^^^^ specifier1                ^^^^ specifier2
```

Comment: as we said in spanish "mil gracias" is like one hundred thanks, i really aprecciate ur help and the tip about using double instead of float. have a great day.